# How to echo and save at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is there an elegant way to both echo a command *and* save it to a file? The common use case is `echo "test" >> someappendedfile.txt`, in which case the command does not appear in bin/bash. By definition, `>>` is a re-direction, so doing both seems like a weird command.

I would like the result of something like `echo "test" >> someappendedfile.txt` to both log to stdout and the appending file.

Is there an alternative operator or utility that does what I am asking?

Comment: FYI -- `echo "foo" >> somefile` is really inefficient if you put `>> somefile` on every line over and over; it re-opens the output every single time you want to run a command and closes it again after. Much more efficient to do your redirection just once: `exec >> somefile` at the top of your script -- or, for the case at hand, `exec > >(tee -a somefile)` to redirect to `tee` (and thus to copy all content *both* to the file and to the original stdout location).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that tee was what I was looking for! Is there a way to change the question title of one of the other posts? The reason I couldn't find the help I was looking for was that I had no idea tee existed!

Comment: That's the point of marking a question duplicate rather than deleting it -- that way other folks can use it as a guidepost to find preexisting questions that are on-point for them, but where they weren't using the right search terms.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks!